# Help with complex variable exercise

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this exercise:
Find the bounded steady temperatures $T (x, y)$ in the semi-infinite solid $y \geq 0$ if $T = 0$ on the part $x < −1$ $(y = 0)$ of the boundary, if $T = 1$ on the part $x > 1$ $(y = 0)$, and if the strip $−1 < x < 1$ $(y = 0)$ of the boundary is insulated.

then $$T(x,0)=0, \;x<-1; \\ \frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y}=0, \; -1<x<1; \\ T(x,0)=1, \; x>1.$$

How can I solve this problem, I have to demonstrate all that I say, then I can't do nothing by inspection. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The tags seems very badly chosen.

Comment: I can't find a tag with conformal-mapping or something like that

Comment: I don't think you want any conformal map. Do the standard separation of variables. But a PDE tag is most appropriate.

Comment: You seem to lack an equation describing the heat out in the part of the half-plane away from the boundary.  You will need some sort of equation to model that heat.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
It's convenient to use polar coordinates $\ds{\pars{r,\theta}}$: $\quad\ds{x \equiv r\cos\pars{\theta}\quad\mbox{and}\quad y = r\sin\pars{\theta}}$. By symmetry reasons we'll consider $\ds{\varphi\pars{r,\theta} = {\rm T}\pars{x,y} - \half}$ and confine our attention to the upper half $\ds{xy}$-plane:
\begin{align}
&\nabla^{2}\varphi\pars{r,\theta}=0\,,\qquad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rclrcl}
\left.\partiald{\varphi\pars{r,0}}{\theta}\right\vert_{\theta\ =\ 0}
& = & 0\,,\quad & r & < & 1
\\[1mm]
\varphi\pars{r,0} & = & \half\,,\quad & r & > & 1
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
\\[3mm]&\mbox{with}\quad \varphi\pars{r,\theta} = -\varphi\pars{r,\pi - \theta}
\tag{2}
\end{align}
$\pars{2}$ reduces the problem to the first quadrant
$\ds{\pars{~0 \leq \theta \leq {\pi \over 2}~}}$.

> The general solution is given by
>   \begin{align}
> \varphi\pars{r,\theta}&=
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{lclrcl}
> a\theta + b + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> A_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta} + B_{n}\cos\pars{n\theta}}r^{n}
> & \mbox{if} & r & < & 1
> \\
> c\theta + d + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> C_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta} + D_{n}\cos\pars{n\theta}}r^{-n}
> & \mbox{if} & r & > & 1
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

$\pars{2}$ reduces this expression to:
\begin{align}
\left.\varphi\pars{r,\theta}\right\vert_{r\ <\ 1}&=
a\pars{\theta - {\pi \over 2}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{
A_{2n}\sin\pars{2n\theta}r^{2n}
+B_{2n + 1}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}r^{2n + 1}}
\\[3mm]
\left.\varphi\pars{r,\theta}\right\vert_{r\ >\ 1}&=
c\pars{\theta - {\pi \over 2}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
C_{2n}\sin\pars{2n\theta}r^{-2n}
+D_{2n + 1}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}r^{-2n - 1}}
\end{align}

> By using the boundary conditions in $\pars{1}$ we find:
>   $$
> a=0\,,\qquad A_{2n} =0\,,\qquad c = -{1 \over \pi}\,,\qquad D_{2n + 1} = 0
> $$
>   The solution is reduced to:
>   \begin{align}
> \varphi\pars{r,\theta}&=
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{lclrcl}
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}B_{2n + 1}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}r^{2n + 1}
> & \mbox{if} & r & < & 1
> \\[2mm]
> \half - {\theta \over \pi} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> C_{2n}\sin\pars{2n\theta}r^{-2n}
> & \mbox{if} & r & > & 1
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

The condition
$\ds{\lim_{r \to 1^{-}}\varphi\pars{r,\theta}
    =\lim_{r \to 1^{+}}\varphi\pars{r,\theta}}$ leads to:
$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}B_{2n + 1}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}
=\half - {\theta \over \pi} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}C_{2n}\sin\pars{2n\theta}}
\tag{3}
$$
With
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{\bracks{2m + 1}\theta}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}
&=&\pi\,\delta_{mn}
\\[3mm]
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{\bracks{2m + 1}\theta}\pars{\half - {\theta \over \pi}}
&=&{1 \over \pars{2m + 1}^{2}\pi}
\\[3mm]
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{\bracks{2m + 1}\theta}\sin\pars{2n + 1\theta}
&=&-\,{2n \over 4n + 1}\,\delta_{mn}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and condition $\pars{3}$ we find
$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\pi B_{2n + 1} + {2n \over 4n + 1}\,C_{2n} = {1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}\pi}}
\tag{4}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2m\theta}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}
&=&-\,{2n \over 4n + 1}\,\delta_{mn}
\\[3mm]
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2m\theta}\pars{\half - {\theta \over \pi}}
&=&{1 \over 4m}
\\[3mm]
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2m\theta}\sin\pars{2n\theta}
&=&{\pi \over 4}\,\delta_{mn}
\end{array}\right.
$$
these expressions and condition $\pars{3}$ leads to
$$
\color{#66f}{\large -\,{2n \over 4n + 1}\,B_{2n + 1} - {\pi \over 4}\,C_{2n}= {1 \over 4n}}\tag{5}
$$

> $\pars{4}$ and $\pars{5}$ determine $\ds{B_{2n + 1}}$ and $\ds{C_{2n}}$.